# Maven2: jars are present but eclipse is showing only pom files

Tags: eclipse, jar, maven-2

I have created a maven project and generated the entities using hibernate tool. Now I have to add ***ejb3-persistence*** dependency to the project path. So whenever I search for the jar, instead of showing jars, eclipse is showing only pom files. But I have the jars in the repository.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue by making the following changes.

1. I opened the directory of ***ejb3-persistence*** in the local maven repository.
2. Checked the ***pom*** file of *ejb3-persistence*. For example ***ejb3-persistence-1.0.2.GA.pom*** in that directory.And I have observed that tag ***packaging*** is having value like ***pom***
3. Then I changed the value in the ***packaging*** tag to ***jar*** and now it starts working.